# Loopback - how to get id of user and insert into related model? (hasMany)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, loopbackjs

What I am trying to figure out is how to get the id of the current authenticated user and use that when creating records in the DB as a foreign key of a different model?

To be more specific I need to get the id of the current authenticated user (model: CommonUser) and use that id as a FK when creating a new Event.

**The relationships:**

I have created a Model based on the User model called CommonUser. Common user has many Events. Event belongs to Common User.

So Event has a foreignKey called commonUserId.

How do I get the id of the user and use that when doing the insert?

*I would have thought this would be automatic as part of the process as far as setting up relationships is concerned? Is that incorrect?*

Also to complicate matters I have an Event Look-Up table (i will worry about this next so don't feel obligated to dive to deep) because Event also hasAndBelongsToMany through Event Lookup.

**User**

```
{
  "name": "CommonUser",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "events": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Event",
      "foreignKey": "eventId",
      "through": "EventLookUp"
    },
    "friends": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "CommonUser",
      "through": "Friend",
      "foreignKey": "friendId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

[image: User]

**Event**

```
{
  "name": "Event",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "radius": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 50
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "geopoint",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "owner": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "CommonUser",
      "foreignKey": "commonUserId"
    },
    "commonUsers": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "CommonUser",
      "foreignKey": "ownerId",
      "through": "EventLookUp"
    },
    "galleries": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Gallery",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "photos": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Photo",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "through": "Gallery"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

[image: Event]

**Event Lookup**

```
{
  "name": "EventLookUp",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

[image: Event LookUp]

If I can be pointed in the right direction that would be fantastic. It's hard to find an answer reading through the documentation. *I think I need to use an operation hook before insert and set the Event Models properties?* What is loopback's best practice as far as this goes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In loopback swagger when you login as a user using loopback's default users/login api , you get access token object as response.You can copy the id of access token and paste into the box in top right corner in swagger and set the access token.Thus internally your accesstoken is set in loopback and for your every request from swagger, loopback append the access token along with the request.In this way you can get the access token from ctx(context) in remote methods.

**For create, findOrCreate, save an event obj:**

```
Event.observe('before save', function updateUserId(ctx, next) {

  let userId = ctx.options.accessToken.userId;`

  if (ctx.instance) {
    ctx.instance.commonUserId = userId;
  }
  next();
});
```

**For updateAttributes for event obj:**

```
Event.observe('before save', function updateUserId(ctx, next) { 

  let userId = ctx.options.accessToken.userId; 

  if (ctx.currentInstance) { 
    ctx.currentInstance.commonUserId = userId;
  } 
  next(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am still learning the intricacies of loopback and honestly javascript more in depth. I come from object oriented programming and procedural PHP programming and it is taking me some time to solidify the ideas of functional programming. Passing around functions as objects (callbacks) hurts my brain :D

Comment: Oh and no threads is wierd. I have been so use to threading I didn't even think about what was really going on. Having to program all asynchronously is a different mindset for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I am unsure if it is best practice or if there is a better way to handle this.

Anyways I created an Operation Hook inside "/common/models/event.js" and appearently you can get access to the context within this hook.

If there is a better way to do this I would like to know.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (Event) {


    Event.observe('before save', function updateForeignKeyCommonUserId(ctx, next) {

        // console.log(ctx.options);
        /* WHAT Options Looks Like */
        // { accessToken:
        // { id: 'Z20R1RsnumWEdDzR3TyCCbmZ0DTp4tOh2cviU6JGsrlNIYCs3KchQ7mdAnhTc1VQ',
        //     ttl: 1209600,
        //     created: 2018-06-26T17:41:28.298Z,
        //     userId: 3 },
        // authorizedRoles: {} }
        // console.log("THE USER ID IS: ");
        // console.log(ctx.options.accessToken.userId); // Current User Id

        var userId = ctx.options.accessToken.userId;

        // So appearently "the context provides either an instance property or a pair of data and where properties"
       // @todo: find out why there can be a 'instance' or 'data'. 
        if (ctx.instance) {
            ctx.instance.commonUserId = userId; // instance
        } else {
            ctx.data.commonUserId = userId; // data
        }
        next();
    });

};
```

If someone wouldn't mind explaining where context comes from and how it gets populated that would be awesome!